# How to reset list to original state in Flutter VSCODE

Tags: flutter

I've been messing around with the information I have found online, but haven't been able to make my code work, please help.

I need my list to be able to restore to its original content.

Here is my code so far:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

List<String> items = ["CGS 1540", "COP 2512", "COP 2513", "CIS 3213",
"CGS 3303", "CIS 3363", "COP 3515", "CEN 3722", "CGS 3853", "CNT 4104",
"CNT 4403", "COP 4538", "CNT 4603", "CIS 4935", "COP 4703" ];

void main() {

  runApp(const MyApp());
}


class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});


   @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: const MyStatefulWidget(),
      ),
    );
  }

}

class MyStatefulWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyStatefulWidget({super.key});

  @override
  _MyStatefulWidgetState createState() => _MyStatefulWidgetState();
}


class _MyStatefulWidgetState extends State<StatefulWidget> {
 List<String>initialData = [];
 
  @override
  void initState() {
    fillInitialData();
    super.initState();
  }

  fillInitialData() {
    initialData.addAll(items);
  }
  


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    const title = 'Course List';


    return MaterialApp(
      title: title,
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text(title),
        ),
      
        body: ListView.builder(
          itemCount: items.length,
          padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical:16),
          prototypeItem: ListTile(
            title: Text(items.first),
          ),
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            return Dismissible(
              background: Container(
                child: Text('Delete ${items[index]}',
                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                ),
                color: Colors.red,
              ),
              secondaryBackground:Container(
                child: Text('Archive ${items[index]}',
                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                ),
                alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
                color: Colors.yellow,
              ),
              key: ValueKey<String>(items[index]),
              onDismissed: (DismissDirection direction){
                if(direction == DismissDirection.startToEnd) {  
                setState(() {
                  String deletedItem = items.removeAt(index);
                  
                   ScaffoldMessenger.of(context)
                   ..removeCurrentSnackBar()
                   ..showSnackBar(
                  
                  SnackBar(
                    duration: const Duration(
                      seconds: 2,
                    ),
                  content: Text('$deletedItem deleted'),
                  action: SnackBarAction(
                  label: 'Undo',
                    onPressed: (){
                      setState(() => items.insert(index, deletedItem));
                    },

                  ),
                  )

            
                   );

              },
            
            );
            } 
            
            else if (direction == DismissDirection.endToStart){
              setState(() {
                  String deletedItem = items.removeAt(index);
                  
                   ScaffoldMessenger.of(context)
                   ..removeCurrentSnackBar()
                   ..showSnackBar(
                  
                  SnackBar(
                    duration: const Duration(
                      seconds: 2,
                    ),
                  content: Text('$deletedItem Archived'),
                  action: SnackBarAction(
                  label: 'Undo',
                    onPressed: (){
                      setState(() => items.insert(index, deletedItem));
                    },

                  ),
                  )
            
                   );

              },
            
            );
            }
          },                  
               child: ListTile(
                title: Text(
                   '${items[index]}',
                )
              )
        );
          },
    ),

      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: (){
          setState(() {
            initialData.clear();
            fillInitialData();
          });
        },
        tooltip: 'Reset',
        child: const Icon(Icons.autorenew),
      ),

    ),
    );
  }
  

}
```

I've looked through many posts I've seen on here, but they have either been with slider or numbers so I am stuck, please just help me figure out how to use the action button to reset the list to its original state before any deletions are archiving was done.

Comment: Your code looks mostly correct.  (Always call super.initState first, but we can overlook that).  What behavior are you seeing that isn't meeting your expectations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So essentially one thing to look out for is that `items.remove` actually modifies the **original list**, meaning that when you remove elements from the list `items`, the removed element will no longer be there.

A *quick fix* to your current code is, since you've already made a copy of the items in `initialData`, is just to clear the items and re-add them to the `items` list since that is what the state of your widget *depends on*

```dart
  floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
          onPressed: () {
            setState(() {
              items.clear();
              items.addAll(initialData);
              initialData.clear();
              fillInitialData();
            });
          },
          tooltip: 'Reset',
          child: const Icon(Icons.autorenew),
        ),
```

**but this code could be much cleaner and here is how if you are interested** (ill try to explain as much as I can)

there are several things that could be improved:

1. your state should not be depending on a global variable and instead you can pass the `items` list to your stateful widget
2. the state object should be the one handling, well... the state, meaning that what ever your

here are the changes I have done to your code to clean it up

firstly, I made the `items` list a constant list of strings and it will be used as a *single source of truth*

```dart
const List<String> items = [
  "CGS 1540",
  "COP 2512",
  "COP 2513",
  "CIS 3213",
  "CGS 3303",
  "CIS 3363",
  "COP 3515",
  "CEN 3722",
  "CGS 3853",
  "CNT 4104",
  "CNT 4403",
  "COP 4538",
  "CNT 4603",
  "CIS 4935",
  "COP 4703"
];
```

secondly, I added a final list attribute to the stateful widget and made the state class extend `State<MyStatefulWidget>` so that we could use that attribute in the state object.

```dart
class MyStatefulWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  final List<String> items;
  const MyStatefulWidget({super.key, required this.items});

  @override
  MyStatefulWidgetState createState() => MyStatefulWidgetState();
}

class MyStatefulWidgetState extends State<MyStatefulWidget> {
...
}
```

now what ever you do to your state will not affect your original widget, and this way you could reuse the same widget for different lists. So that being said, I added a List of string attribute in the state class that will be used for the state so whenever the state needs to be updated, **that list should be modified**.

So something like this can now be done

```dart
 List<String> items = [];

  @override
  void initState() {
    fillInitialData();
    super.initState();
  }

  fillInitialData() {
    items.clear();
    items.addAll(widget.items);
  }

....

 floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
          onPressed: () {
            setState(() {
              fillInitialData();
            });
          },
          tooltip: 'Reset',
          child: const Icon(Icons.autorenew),
),
```

finally, here is the modified full code

## full code

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

const List<String> items = [
  "CGS 1540",
  "COP 2512",
  "COP 2513",
  "CIS 3213",
  "CGS 3303",
  "CIS 3363",
  "COP 3515",
  "CEN 3722",
  "CGS 3853",
  "CNT 4104",
  "CNT 4403",
  "COP 4538",
  "CNT 4603",
  "CIS 4935",
  "COP 4703"
];

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: MyStatefulWidget(
          items: items,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyStatefulWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  final List<String> items;
  const MyStatefulWidget({super.key, required this.items});

  @override
  MyStatefulWidgetState createState() => MyStatefulWidgetState();
}

class MyStatefulWidgetState extends State<MyStatefulWidget> {
  List<String> items = [];

  @override
  void initState() {
    fillInitialData();
    super.initState();
  }

  fillInitialData() {
    items.clear();
    items.addAll(widget.items);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    const title = 'Course List';

    return MaterialApp(
      title: title,
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text(title),
        ),
        body: ListView.builder(
          itemCount: items.length,
          padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 16),
          prototypeItem: ListTile(
            title: Text(items.first),
          ),
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            return Dismissible(
                background: Container(
                  color: Colors.red,
                  child: Text(
                    'Delete ${items[index]}',
                    style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                  ),
                ),
                secondaryBackground: Container(
                  alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
                  color: Colors.yellow,
                  child: Text(
                    'Archive ${items[index]}',
                    style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                  ),
                ),
                key: ValueKey<String>(items[index]),
                onDismissed: (DismissDirection direction) {
                  if (direction == DismissDirection.startToEnd) {
                    setState(
                      () {
                        String deletedItem = items.removeAt(index);

                        ScaffoldMessenger.of(context)
                          ..removeCurrentSnackBar()
                          ..showSnackBar(SnackBar(
                            duration: const Duration(
                              seconds: 2,
                            ),
                            content: Text('$deletedItem deleted'),
                            action: SnackBarAction(
                              label: 'Undo',
                              onPressed: () {
                                setState(
                                    () => items.insert(index, deletedItem));
                              },
                            ),
                          ));
                      },
                    );
                  } else if (direction == DismissDirection.endToStart) {
                    setState(
                      () {
                        String deletedItem = items.removeAt(index);

                        ScaffoldMessenger.of(context)
                          ..removeCurrentSnackBar()
                          ..showSnackBar(SnackBar(
                            duration: const Duration(
                              seconds: 2,
                            ),
                            content: Text('$deletedItem Archived'),
                            action: SnackBarAction(
                              label: 'Undo',
                              onPressed: () {
                                setState(
                                    () => items.insert(index, deletedItem));
                              },
                            ),
                          ));
                      },
                    );
                  }
                },
                child: ListTile(
                    title: Text(
                  items[index],
                )));
          },
        ),
        floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
          onPressed: () {
            setState(() {
              fillInitialData();
            });
          },
          tooltip: 'Reset',
          child: const Icon(Icons.autorenew),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for going into detail about everything! It helps everything make more sense. You saved me and helped me learn a bit more, I appreciate you!!! :)